# How to split array data returned from json string in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have json return string like given below. I want to extract cancellation Policy list of objects like cutoff Time and refund In Percentage. I tried using for-loop but it didn't help me. Can you please help me on extracting this.

```
Array ( 
[apiStatus] => Array ( [success] => 1 [message] => SUCCESS ) <br>
[apiAvailableBuses] => Array ( <br>
 [0] => Array ( [droppingPoints] => [availableSeats] => 41 <br>[partialCancellationAllowed] => [arrivalTime] => 08:00 AM <br>
  [cancellationPolicy] => [<br>
   {"cutoffTime":"1","refundInPercentage":"10"},<br>
   {"cutoffTime":"2","refundInPercentage":"50"},<br>
   {"cutoffTime":"4","refundInPercentage":"90"}<br>
   ] <br>
   [boardingPoints] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [time] => 09:00PM [location] => Ameerpet,|Jeans Corner 9687452130 [id] => 6 ) [1] => Array ( [time] => 09:15PM [location] => S.R Nagar,S.R Nagar [id] => 2224 ) [2] => Array ( [time] => 09:10PM [location] => Kondapur,Toyota Show room [id] => 2244 ) ) [operatorName] => Deepak Travels [departureTime] => 9:00 PM [mTicketAllowed] => [idProofRequired] => [serviceId] => 6622 [fare] => 800 [busType] => 2+1 Hi-Tech Non A/c [routeScheduleId] => 6622 [commPCT] => 0 [operatorId] => 213 [inventoryType] => 0 ) <br>
 [1] => Array ( [droppingPoints] => [availableSeats] => 41 [partialCancellationAllowed] => [arrivalTime] => 07:00 AM <br>
 [cancellationPolicy] => [<br>
 {"cutoffTime":"1","refundInPercentage":"10"},<br>
 {"cutoffTime":"2","refundInPercentage":"50"},<br>
 {"cutoffTime":"4","refundInPercentage":"90"}<br>
 ] <br>
 [boardingPoints] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [time] => 09:10PM [location] => Ameerpet,|Jeans Corner [id] => 6 ) [1] => Array ( [time] => 09:00PM [location] => S.R Nagar,S.R Nagar [id] => 2224 ) [2] => Array ( [time] => 08:30PM [location] => KUKATPALLY,JNTU [id] => 2230 ) ) [operatorName] => Dhanunjayabus [departureTime] => 9:00 PM [mTicketAllowed] => [idProofRequired] => [serviceId] => 6743 [fare] => 900 [busType] => VOLVO [routeScheduleId] => 6743 [commPCT] => 0 [operatorId] => 233 [inventoryType] => 0 )
 )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `foreach()` for it like so:

```
foreach ($your_response['apiAvailableBuses'] as $el) {
    $cancellationPolicy[] = $el['cancellationPolicy'];
}
```

Comment: Hi Rax - it is giving array of cancellationPolicy, can we extract data for cutoffTime also ? as i was trying but getting error

Comment: Yes you can. You can do so like this as an example: `$cancellationPolicy[0]->cutoffTime`.

Comment: Hi Rax- i tried same what u mentioned and it throwing error like 'get property of non-object'. am i missing anything  ?

Comment: foreach($someArray2['apiAvailableBuses'] as $s2)
{
$cancellationPolicy[] = $s2['cancellationPolicy'];
echo $cancellationPolicy[0]->cutoffTime.'<br>';
}

Comment: Hi Rax, Can you please help me on this.

Comment: i just tried for one say example [{"cutoffTime":"1","refundInPercentage":"50"},{"cutoffTime":"3","refundInPercentage":"70"},{"cutoffTime":"6","refundInPercentage":"90"}], but getting above mentioned error

Comment: here is the code what i tried ..foreach($someArray2['apiAvailableBuses'] as $s2)
{
if ($s2['routeScheduleId']==5640){
$cancellationPolicy[] = $s2['cancellationPolicy'];
echo '<br>'.$cancellationPolicy[0]->cutoffTime;}
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($data['apiStatus']['apiAvailableBuses'] as $item) {
    foreach($item['cancellationPolicy'] as $key => $json) {
        $jsonDecoded = json_decode($json, true);
        // And you will have access to the data like this
        // $jsonDecoded['cutoffTime'];
        // $jsonDecoded['refundInPercentage'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$response = json_decode($apiResponse);
$cancellationPolicies = [];

foreach ($response->apiAvailableBuses as $availableBus) {

    $cancellationPolicies[] = $availableBus['cancellationPolicy'];

    // if you want to display something you can simply do it like this;

    echo $availableBus['cancellationPolicy']->cutoffTime;
}
```

Comment: followed the same approach but getting error 'Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array ' at line (foreach ($someArray2['apiAvailableBuses'] as $availableBus) {)